# Elasticsearch range query on range field in query string query

Tags: elasticsearch

We're in the process of updating our Elasticsearch from 5.2 to 5.6, and also preparing for an update to 6.x and then 7.x later.

After the update from 5.2 to 5.6, and after creating new indices with all our documents, we noticed something wasn't working as before.

When using a query string query (i.e. ?q=...), we used to be able to do range queries on range fields. But after the update, this results in an error.

For example, we have a field mapping like this:

```
"typicalAgeRange": {
    "type": "integer_range"
}
```

In the past we were able to do a query like this:

```
?q=typicalAgeRange:[0 TO 12]
```

And this would return all documents that had an age range that intersected with 0-12. (For example 6-8, 6-14, 0-4, etc)

However, when we run the same query now on 5.6, we get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"query_string\" : {\n    \"query\" : \"typicalAgeRange:[0 TO 12]\",\n    \"fields\" : [ ],\n    \"use_dis_max\" : true,\n    \"tie_breaker\" : 0.0,\n    \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n    \"auto_generate_phrase_queries\" : false,\n    \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n    \"enable_position_increments\" : true,\n    \"fuzziness\" : \"AUTO\",\n    \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n    \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n    \"phrase_slop\" : 0,\n    \"analyze_wildcard\" : false,\n    \"escape\" : false,\n    \"split_on_whitespace\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
        "index_uuid": "4XB5FxxVSvq1pDxvTRRS3Q",
        "index": "udb3_core_v20201014145500"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "udb3_core_v20201014145500",
        "node": "sXvyyNlvRPyfYo3Gk2aC0g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: {\n  \"query_string\" : {\n    \"query\" : \"typicalAgeRange:[0 TO 12]\",\n    \"fields\" : [ ],\n    \"use_dis_max\" : true,\n    \"tie_breaker\" : 0.0,\n    \"default_operator\" : \"or\",\n    \"auto_generate_phrase_queries\" : false,\n    \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n    \"enable_position_increments\" : true,\n    \"fuzziness\" : \"AUTO\",\n    \"fuzzy_prefix_length\" : 0,\n    \"fuzzy_max_expansions\" : 50,\n    \"phrase_slop\" : 0,\n    \"analyze_wildcard\" : false,\n    \"escape\" : false,\n    \"split_on_whitespace\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}",
          "index_uuid": "4XB5FxxVSvq1pDxvTRRS3Q",
          "index": "udb3_core_v20201014145500",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Field [typicalAgeRange] of type [integer_range] does not support range queries"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I now read in the docs for both 5.2 and 5.6:

> Ranges can be specified for date, numeric or string fields.

5.2: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges

5.6: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges

So it seems like this was never officially supported (or not documented)?
But why did it work before then, and not anymore now?

We still have 5.2 running in production for now, and the same query still works there.

**Update**: Some more information.

If we do a range query in a JSON body, we do get the expected results. For example:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "typicalAgeRange" : {
                "gte" : 0,
                "lte" : 12,
                "boost" : 2.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
{
   "took":6,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":6,
      "max_score":2.0,
      "hits":[
        ... // ommited for brevity
      ]
   }
}
```

So the JSON range query seems to work fine on range fields. However, we also need it to work in the Lucene syntax for multiple reasons. (Backwards compatibility being one of the obvious ones because we have some systems that use this syntax and we cannot refactor that now.)

Comment: What happens when you transform this query string into a standard `range` query? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-range-query.html Same error?

Comment: I remember I had that error 3-4 years ago (ish)... however, it's been fixed and by testing this on the latest version it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @joe. I updated my question with some more information since it was a bit too much to post in a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Val. So the only solution would be updating to 6.x or 7.x? That's our plan anyway, but we had hoped to update to 5.6 first so we could use field collapsing and then take some time to make our document types compatible with 6.x since in that version we can no longer have multiple document types in the same index.

Comment: I'm trying to remember when exactly that was fixed... I'll update here once I find... It was introduced [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26555)

Comment: The issue was [introduced in 5.5.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25950) and supposedly fixed in 5.6 ad 6.0... though it was slightly different than the one you're encountering

Comment: Are you sure that's the same issue? Because we're getting the error on 5.6.16. And the question in the Github issue is about a JSON range query, not the Lucene syntax.

Comment: The fix also seems very specific to term queries, while we're trying to do a range query: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/25918/files

Comment: Okay thanks for the help @val. We'll try downgrading to 5.3 for now so we can use field collapsing, and then update to 6.x later once our document types are compatible.

Comment: I know it's slightly different, but I can't find it anymore... but if memory serves, it was definitely fixed in 6.0. I'll keep looking